# How to convert UploadedFile object to Swift_Mime_MimeEntity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, swiftmailer

I have a Symfony 3.3 contact form that sends an email. Now I am trying to add an attachment to the form. I insert the following line in my sendEmail function:

```
        ->attach($data["attachment"])
```

... and I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::attach() must implement
>   interface Swift_Mime_MimeEntity, instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile given

So my question is: **How do I convert my UploadedFile object into something that SwiftMailer will be happy with?**

====

Edit #1: I tried this with no success:

```
$fullFilePath = $data["attachment"]->getPath() . '/' . $data["attachment"]->getClientOriginalName();
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($fullFilePath);
```

Attaching that "attachment" just resulted in the email not being sent, though the application acted as if it had sent the form.

====

Edit #2: Progress! I'm now able to get a useful error. This code ...

```
        $extension = $data["attachment"]->guessExtension();
    if($extension !== 'rtf'){
        die('Please give us an rtf file. TODO: Put a better message here!');
    }
    $newFilePath = '/tmp';
    $newFileName = 'temporary.rtf';
    $data["attachment"]->move($newFilePath, $newFileName);
```

... gives me an error like this:

> Could not move the file "/tmp/phpnIqXDr" to "/tmp/temporary.rtf" ()

... which is very frustrating, since I know that `/tmp` is writeable by every user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to move the file, Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile class returns the path and has methods to get the filename and mimetype.

This code works for me:

```
$message->attach(
    \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($data["attachment"])
        ->setFilename(
            $data["attachment"]->getClientOriginalName()
        )
        ->setContentType(
            $data["attachment"]->getClientMimeType()
        )
);
```

Credit to [toolpixx](https://gist.github.com/toolpixx/1b4b02d687aeb9993be9)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
private function sendEmail($data)
{
    $vgmsContactMail = self::contactMail;
    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
    /* @var $uploadedFile UploadedFile */
    $uploadedFile = $data["attachment"];
    $extension = $uploadedFile->guessExtension();
    if(!in_array($extension, ['pdf','rtf']) ){
        die('Please upload a .pdf or .rtf file.');
    }
    $newFilePath = '/tmp';
    $newFileName = 'temporary' . rand(0,10000) . '.rtf';
    $uploadedFile->move($newFilePath, $newFileName);
    $attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/tmp/' . $newFileName);
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance("VGMS Contact Form: ". $data["subject"])
        ->setFrom(array($vgmsContactMail => "Message by ".$data["name"]))
        ->setTo(array(
            $vgmsContactMail => $vgmsContactMail
        ))
        ->setBody($data["message"]."<br>ContactMail :".$data["email"])
        ->attach($attachment)
    ;
    return $mailer->send($message);
}
```